# Next.Js - useState is resetting dropdown values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am creating a shopping page. I am keeping a JSON to store the product details. I have created the product as a component and using it in the shopping page. For each product I am keeping a drop down to select the quantity (0-5, default value is 0).

Whenever a drop down value change happens, I am making a call back to the parent which is the product page where I am updating the total count. I am using `useState` hook to update the total. The issue is that when I call the `setState`, the drop down is not showing the selected value, but the default one (My strong guess is that the drop downs are getting reset. When I remove the setState call, the drop downs work fine).

I am using `react-dropdown` for implementing drop down.

Parent Component:

```
const [total,setCartTotal] = useState(0)
const calculateTotalCartValue = (count) => {
    setCartTotal(total+count)
}

// Adding the child Component
<Cartitem 
   parentCallback={calculateTotalCartValue}
/>
```

Child Component:

```
const calculateTotal = (event) => {
    console.log(event) // This is properly printing the selected drop down details
    parentCallback(2) // for testing I am passing value 2
}

// Drop down
<Dropdown 
   
    options={options} // I have a list of options
    value={defaultOption}
    onChange={calculateTotal}
/>
```

Comment: use this () => total+count in setCartTotal , I think it will fix that , you must change state async .

Comment: when the you make the change and useState is called it triggers a re-render. you have `value` set to `defaultOption`

Comment: @mazdak Close, if you want to use a functional state update then you should reference the previous state, i.e. `setCartTotal(total => total + count)`. `setCartTotal(() => total + count)` would be no different than OP's code.

Comment: it is obvious , IDE will through error , of course i mean t => t + c

Comment: @dirkenstocks yeah! Make sense. I tried and it is working. But, I want to keep a default value. How will I do that if I remove the `value` ?

Comment: @AKA not sure I'd remove it all together. I understand the need for it, I was only pointing out why it was happening. You could try using `React.memo()` on your `CartItem` component, I'm not sure how heavy it is or what all it includes but off the top of my head I think that might work.

Comment: Or you could implement some sort of flag to determine what the `value` property should be, i.e. `<Dropdown value={userHasSetCount ? count : defaultOption} ... />`

Comment: It's unclear why you are using an semi-controlled input. You are setting the value to something that doesn't appear to change. Can you share a more comprehensive code example for the `Cartitem` child component? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese I'm guessing OP was referencing `react-dropdown`'s documentation.